# Any good resources for book rating data?

Tags: data-request

I'm writing a python script that collects book ratings and analyses them using bayesian statistical models. I only need numerical ratings (e.g. percentiles, stars, 10 point scale). Any other attributes of the review are extraneous. It is important that I have the number of ratings per rating level and not just the total number of ratings and the average rating. For example, if the book has been given a rating of 4.3 out of 5 stars with a total of 5,000 ratings, I need to know exactly how many of those 5,000 ratings are 5 stars, 4 stars, 3 stars, ect.

So far I've only found this kind of detailed information on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21.A_Short_History_of_Nearly_Everything). I've looked into scraping amazon but this seems clunky given that the desired information is stored on separate pages and would require 5-6 page scrapes per book.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to databases or websites where this kind of rating information for books is available either through an api or scraping?

Answer (score 1):

The links may help. The first is to the Douban Book Rating Dataset. It is the largest book review website in China. The second is a collection of Amazon ratings the was web scraped already by a user on Kaggle. Those are all I know of.  Hope they help.

http://opendata.pku.edu.cn/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.18170/DVN/LA9GRH

https://www.kaggle.com/shrutimehta/amazon-book-reviews-webscraped#Input.csv